# compare and complete lists with each other

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have here a very tricky task here.I want to compare x number of lists in list of lists and that lists contain dictionaries.So i want to compare the dictionaries in these lists based on the 'name' key in the dictionaries if it match it should pass if not it should copy the whole dictionary to the lists that don't have it with editing the 'balance' key vlaue to '0'.

For example let's assume we have list of lists like this :

```
list_of_lists=[[{'name': u'Profit','balance': 10},{'name': u'Income','balance': 30},{'name': u'NotIncome','balance': 15}],[{'name': u'Profit','balance': 20},{'name': u'Income','balance': 10}]]
```

So the result should be :

```
list_of_lists=[[{'name': u'Profit','balance': 10},{'name': u'Income','balance': 30},{'name': u'NotIncome','balance': 15}],[{'name': u'Profit','balance': 20},{'name': u'Income','balance': 10},{'name': u'NotIncome','balance': 0}]]
```

Here is my code but i can't get it work with 2 lists or more(I don't know the number of lists in the list (maybe 2,3 or 4 etc...) :

```
for line in lines:
   for d1, d2 in zip(line[0], line[1]):
           for key, value in d1.items():
               if value != d2[key]:
                   print key, value, d2[key]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first create a `set` containing all the names and then iterate the sublists one by one adding the missing dicts:

```
import pprint

l = [
        [
            {'name': u'Profit','balance': 10},
            {'name': u'Income','balance': 30},
            {'name': u'NotIncome','balance': 15}
        ],
        [
            {'name': u'Profit','balance': 20},
            {'name': u'Income','balance': 10}
        ],
        []
    ]

all_names = {d['name'] for x in l for d in x}
for sub_list in l:
    for name in (all_names - {d['name'] for d in sub_list}):
        sub_list.append({'name': name, 'balance': 0})

pprint.pprint(l)
```

Output:

```
[[{'balance': 10, 'name': u'Profit'},
  {'balance': 30, 'name': u'Income'},
  {'balance': 15, 'name': u'NotIncome'}],
 [{'balance': 20, 'name': u'Profit'},
  {'balance': 10, 'name': u'Income'},
  {'balance': 0, 'name': u'NotIncome'}],
 [{'balance': 0, 'name': u'Profit'},
  {'balance': 0, 'name': u'Income'},
  {'balance': 0, 'name': u'NotIncome'}]]
```

That said you should consider converting sublists to dicts where keys are names and values are balances in order to ease the processing.

Comment: Your answer is GREAT!. I really liked it have only one doubt here : What if the dictionary contain another key which it may be different from another ?! Like i have another key called 'type' with value 'type1' or 'type 2 ' etc.. how should i copy that to my new dictionary ?!